# Delete items from a list if the item contains an entry in a blacklist

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
lst = [
    {'name': 'dave', 'age': 23, 'friends': ['richard', 'mike']},
    {'name': 'bob', 'age': 26, 'friends': ['tom', 'mike', 'steve']}, 
    {'name': 'bill', 'age': 30, 'friends': ['tom', 'jeff']},
    {'name': 'nathan', 'age': 32, 'friends': ['steve', 'mike']}
]
```

and I have a "blacklist"

```
blacklist = ['steve', 'richard']
```

I want to get rid of all dictionaries that have a blacklisted name in their `friends` list - in this case I would be left with just `bill`:

```
lst = [
    {'name': 'bill', 'age': 30, 'friends': ['tom', 'jeff']}
]
```

Every time I try to approach this I end up with this crazy set of loops - adding indexes to a list then iterating over it again and removing items at that index.  I'm assuming there is a better way.  I'm not sure if I should be using a type of nested list comprehension or perhaps a lambda.

Comment: If you are going to tackle more complicated things later on, I would consider representing your data as a [network](https://networkx.github.io/). Here, you just remove the neighbours of Steve and Richard.

Comment: If you're lists are really big, it also might be worth it to try out an in-place solution.  The answers so far will require twice the memory of your original list of dicts if no matches occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use list comprehension with filtering condition like this

```
[itm for itm in lst if all(friend not in blacklist for friend in itm["friends"])]
```

In case, if the `blacklist` is a bigger list, you might want to convert that to a `set`, like this

```
blacklist = {'steve', 'richard'}
```

Sets will provide faster lookups than the lists, since the lookup happens in constant time in Sets, where as it happens in liner time in lists.

The advantage of using `all` is that, it short-circuits and returns immediately if the one of the iterations give false. So, in most cases, the entire iterable need not be consumed.

Comment: I think `all(friend not in blacklist...)` and `any(friend in blacklist...)` will both short-circuit the exact same way, won't they?  As soon as `friend` is in `blacklist`, they return.

Comment: @dano Correct, they both short-circuit.

Comment: @thefourtheye This worked perfectly - thanks.  As a followup, any recommendations on where to learn more about list comprehensions?

Comment: @diplosaurus When I stated learning, I followed more questions and their answers in Stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's it is as a one-liner:

```
out = [d for d in lst if not any(x in blacklist for x in d['friends'])]
```

Output:

```
[{'age': 30, 'friends': ['tom', 'jeff'], 'name': 'bill'}]
```

We build a new list, filtering out items where any item in `d['friends']` is also in our `blacklist`.

The other answers' notes about sets are correct, however. If you're dealing with large lists you should definitely be using them, though you probably won't notice much difference with smaller list sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You can efficiently test if any friends are in the blacklist if you convert both lists to sets. Then it's a simple set intersection to see if there are any overlaps.

Try this:

```
blacklist = set(blacklist)

lst = [item for item in lst if not set(item["friends"]) & blacklist]
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are all good, but the problem can be solved in-place as well without creating a new list with the old list.  Don't know if this is what you're looking for, but it's worth having it posted here,

```
i=0
while( len(lst) > i ):    
    if any( x in blacklist for x in lst[i]['friends'] ):
        del(lst[i])
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Overall I like the list comprehension a little more because it challenges me to do things in a more "pythonic" way, but I appreciate this answer because it's easier to understand.

Comment: List comprehensions are great.  But if you get into a memory bound situation, this may be the only way.